# String value with double quote in C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I was trying to do autocomplete for my input box. When user start typing **"I**, then I should exactly search the keyword what user has typed (**"I**). When keys pressed, I was getting the string value as **"\"I**. How can i do the search based on what user has entered without stripping off any character from the string. Pls provide me any suggestion to help my issue.

**Sample Code**

```
public JsonResult AutoBibs(string searchTerm)
{
   model = (from line in db.BibContents
                     where (line.Value.StartsWith(searchTerm) || line.Value.Contains(" " + searchTerm))
                     select new PoDetails
                     {
                         BibId = line.BibId
                     }).ToList(); 
return model;
}
```

Comment: I guess, you have looked at the string with the debugger? The debugger display \" for "

Comment: @Jan. Yes. I have checked with the debugger only. But when querying the keyword (\") in the LINQ, the expected result is not populating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `"` always appends with an Escape character while processing the String variables in C# i.e. it appends `"\"` at the beginning. It would not change your functionality and you can still continue with your Auto Complete feature. Generally you can find this during in `DEBUG` mode only.

Read this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx) article for more details.